# React - Are all state properties required to be returned by getDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When using the `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle method in a React component, does the state that is returned fully overwrite the components' existing state, or does it simply update the specific state properties that are returned? For example,

```
class foo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      one: true,
      two: false,
    }
  }

  getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    ...
    return {
      one: false,
    }
  }

  ...  
}
```

Will the state be:

```
{ one: false }
```

or

```
{
  one: false,
  two: false,
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will update the piece of state that is present in the object you return and leave the other state untouched, [as it is stated in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops):

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render
>   method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should
>   return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { one: 1 };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps() {
    return { two: 2 };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```